# passing a string created by python $(python -c "print ' ls ' ") to C main

Tags: python, c, stdin

I am trying to pass a string to a C program which expects a user input (read(0, input, 100). I want to pass a string automatically.

Here is what I do:

```
$(python -c "print '                    ls'") | ./myprog
```

somehow myprog does not get the string passed.

I am at miss to which is the correct way to accomplish my task. This is on Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the program to show us? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: I am not trying to pass arguments to main. main calls func() which asks
for input from stdin using read(0, inputbuffer, 100)

I want to create the inputbuffer in a python script and pass it to main.